# how to write a boost::geometry::index::satisfies() that can be as good performance as bgi::intersect()

Tags: c++, boost, geometry

I want to search boxes in the rtree by intersecting but not touching a given box, which is slightly different from bgi::intersect(). Then I write a struct IntersectNoTouch(no c++11 supported in my enviroment) and apply it to the query function, and it performs very very very poorly by costing more time than bgi::intersect().
SO MY QUESTOIN is, how to make a customized efficient struct or some sort of method that would do the work.

```
struct IntersectNoTouch
{
    rt_box_t const& _base;

    IntersectNoTouch(rt_box_t const& base)
        : _base(base)
    {
    }

    bool operator()(rt_value_t const& p) const
    {
      return !(p.first.min_corner().get<0>() >= _base.max_corner().get<0>()
                 || _base.min_corner().get<0>() >= p.first.max_corner().get<0>()
                 || p.first.min_corner().get<1>() >= _base.max_corner().get<1>()
                 || _base.min_corner().get<1>() >= p.first.max_corner().get<1>()); 
    }
};

typedef bg::model::point<int, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> rt_point_t;
typedef bg::model::box<rt_point_t> rt_box_t;
typedef std::pair<rt_box_t, unsigned> rt_value_t;
typedef bgi::dynamic_rstar rtree_parameters_t;
typedef bgi::rtree<rt_value_t, rtree_parameters_t> rtree_t;

rtree_t _rtBlk...
...
_rtBlk.query(bgi::satisfies(IntersectNoTouch(_elements[i]->rtBloatBbox())), boost::make_function_output_iterator(myCallback));
```